# redux reducer is messing up my api calls somehow

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a very strang behavior in my react + rails app:
When I request some data from the backend everything works as expected up to the point when I want to store this conversation in redux:
[Normal response with the conversation property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN6UI.png)

But when I want to store it in redux, the conversation property is empty in the response [conversation missing in the response, how is this possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOHOG.png) ?
Thats my action where I log this response:

```
const url = process.env.REACT_APP_API

export function getConversations(task, headers) {
  console.log(headers)
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log('task:', task)
    const path = `tasks/${task}`
    axios
      .get(url + path, headers)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CONVERSATIONS,
          payload: response.data.data,
        })
      })
```

and thats my reducer, It's enough to delete one letter in the reducer and I start getting a proper responses as in postman:

```
const InitialConversations = []

export default function conversations(state = InitialConversations, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CONVERSATIONS:
      return action.payload.conversations
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and I'm calling it this way:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    activeIndex: Number(this.props.match.params.id),
}}
     componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getConversations(this.state.activeIndex, this.props.headers)
  }
```

Comment: Seems like you are wiping out state after an action in your reducer `return {...state, conversations: action.payload.conversations)`

Comment: Ok, this might be the part of the problem. I keep my headers in redux.
Thanks